# Get Print status from Java

Tags: java, printing

**We have a requirement that get the print status from java printing.**
see this little program.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class TestPrint
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if (pj.printDialog())
    {
      try
      {
        System.out.println("Done");

      }
      catch (PrinterException exc)
      {
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After running this print dialog comes.It has 'OK' and 'Cancel' button.**We need to get whether user click the 'OK' button or not.**

Comment: I think there are two different question here. You need to catch mouse click action? or you only need to find what is the status of printing job?

Comment: Actually we have a logic that we only provide print once.So if any one print once not allowed again.How we capture mouse event this dialog comes from rt.jar

Comment: I have edited the question.If user click only the OK button from the dialog it returns TRUE.Now know the answer.

Comment: 'We need to get whether user click the 'OK' button or not' - Isn't that what `pj.printDialog()` is doing?

Comment: Yes later i only came in to know.Thank you very much